Order execution data in pine-script indicator
Is there a way to get the order execution data in a pine-script indicator? I'm looking to plot order executions on a chart. I'm not interested in the strategy tester or backtesting. This is for a live chart.

What do you mean by order execution? What exactly do you want to see on your chart?

Similar to when you check 'Execution labels' under settings, I want to get the order filled data (price and quantity).

Try strategy.opentrades.* collection built-ins
